# pigpio.write doesn't properly set the output

Tags: gpio, pigpio

I am currently trying to control an air conditioner via GPIO pins on the raspberry pi. For that I need to send a command with a length of 24 bytes via one pin (self.sendPin). I use the following code for that:

```
# Header
self.GPIO.write(self.sendPin, 1)
usleep(3350)
self.GPIO.write(self.sendPin, 0)
usleep(1700)
self.GPIO.write(self.sendPin, 1)
usleep(400)

byte = ""
alternations = 0

self.GPIO.set_mode(self.sendPin, pigpio.OUTPUT)

# Send Command
for i in range(0, 28):
    mask = 1
    while mask < 0xff:

        # Send Bit 1
        if self.cBytes[i] & mask:
            byte += "1"
            self.GPIO.write(self.sendPin, 0)
            usleep(1250)
            self.GPIO.write(self.sendPin, 1)

        # Send Bit 0
        else:
            byte += "0"
            self.GPIO.write(self.sendPin, 0)
            usleep(500)
            self.GPIO.write(self.sendPin, 1)

        alternations += 1

        # Delay between Bits
        usleep(400)

        # Shift Mask
        mask <<= 1
```

After sending this command I can check "alternations" which is 224 and the byte string (which has 224 characters and has the correct bits written to it). However the AC does not respond to that message.

In order to find out whats wrong I electrically connected the send pin on the Raspi to another free pin, and using another program I tried to "read" the command, just by checking how often the pin rises an falls (alternations). Interestingly I rarely get 224 here, which should be the case. Most times some bits/alternations are lost and I get around 200-220. So no wonder the AC does not recognize my command. Why is that?

BTW, I use "usleep", because we have a C program for exactly that task which works fine (also on the pi). In order to avoid that the python time.sleep() method plays any role I decided to use the exact same function from C for sleeping:

```
import ctypes

libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6")
usleep = lambda x: libc.usleep(int(x))
```

EDIT: I just tried reverting to time.sleep() and interestingly this actually makes it worse. Now I only receive about 130-190 pulses. Does it have to do with an improper sleep function?

Comment: Have you looked into the *new-ish* `libgpiod2` C library?

Comment: @Seamus there is nothing in libgpiod (i.e. the new Linux /dev/gpiochip interface) which would help with the questioners problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was a combination of a few things:

1. Use pigpiod*
2. Use the wave_add_generic method (thank you @joan)
3. Check your signal via oscilloscope if possible. In my case I additionally had to scale my edge times by 0.5, because the signal I sent was too long for the AC Unit to understand. So the edge times used in Python had to be half as high as the ones that were used for the C++ program.

*I tried to use RPi.GPIO but it does not work for that task: specifically the LevelChange callback does not come with a tick parameter, so you have to aquire a "tick" by yourself, i.e. by calling time.time_ns(). However this leads to problems when working with high frequency signals. The pigpio library delivers a tick count with the level change callback which works fine. Also for the write part, pigpio delivers a wave_add_generic method which should be used for sending high frequency signals.

Answer (score 2):

pigpio is a poor choice for the method you are using (i.e. using the write() method).

The pigpio Python module is implemented with a client server model.  The client being the pigpio Python script and the server being the pigpio daemon.  Each GPIO write requires a message travelling to and from the pigpio daemon.  That in itself can take half a millisecond.

If you want to stick to that method you would be better off using the RPi.GPIO module.

With pigpio you need to use waves if you want accurate timing of GPIO outputs.

http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#wave_add_generic

Comment: That's funny because I used RPi.GPIO before and read somewhere that I should use pigpio instead. Also the working c++ program uses pigpio. Anyway, RPi.GPIO didn't work either. But I am going to take a look into the wave method.

Comment: pigpio is the library to use for this purpose, but you have to choose the correct method and that is using waves. Perhaps have a look at http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_irrp_py